# initializing array of string in binary search tree

Tags: c++, c, string, tree, binary-search-tree

my node contains an int and a string variable, and I tried using binary search tree. the code is as follow:

```
struct node{
int a;
string members[5];
};

int main(){
node * root = NULL;
root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
root->members[0] = "aaaaa";
return 0;
}
```

of course, my code wasn't exactly like that, I made it short in main because I want to show just the problem. it gave me 'access violation writing location'. I tried using 'new node();' instead of malloc and that didn't happen. why is this exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc()` only allocates memory. It doesn't call the constructor of the object. You could call the constructor on allocated memory using, e.g.

```
void* mem = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (mem) {
    node* root = new(mem) node;
    // ...
}
```

When using `new node` instead of `malloc(sizeof(node)` the allocate memory also gets initialized. Using an uninitialized object is undefined behavior.

Comment: I get it now :D so the problem is there because string is a class. I overlooked an important fact here lol. thank you :D

Comment: @Rei: actually, conceptually all objects in C++ need to be constructed with `new`. For certain types (POD) it also works to just allocate the memory but there is nothing wrong `new`ing these objects and doing so is actually simpler than using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` only allocates raw storage. `new` allocates raw storage *and* initializes it to contain a specified type.

If you're allocating only POD types, that distinction is mostly one of wording, with little real difference in what happens.

If you're allocating something like an `std::string` that has a constructor, there's a world of difference though. If you use `new`, then your `string` variables have all been initialized so they're real (albeit, still empty) strings. When you just use `malloc`, they haven't been initialized at all--they're just chunks of uninitialized raw storage the right size to contain a `string`. When you try to use them as a string, a quick crash is about the best you can hope for.